# Looping frame by frame animation

Tags: android, animation, frame

I'm trying to get my animation to run only 6 times, I set the **`oneshot="true"`** and tried to loop the animation but it doesn't work, the animation still runs only once.

Any help is much appreciated.

**Here is the code**

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  android:oneshot="true">
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/image" android:duration="100" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/image1" android:duration="100" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/image2" android:duration="100" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/image3" android:duration="100" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/image4" android:duration="100" />
 </animation-list>
```

.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        img.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.anime);
        AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable)img.getBackground();
        frameAnimation.setCallback(img);
        frameAnimation.setVisible(true, true);
        frameAnimation.start();
   }
```

Comment: You need to wait for each run to finish before starting the next one.

Comment: @Amanni: yu got to set the oneshot false and not true. and also try with the **android:repeatCount** property

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    img.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.anime);
    AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable)img.getBackground();
    frameAnimation.setCallback(img);
    frameAnimation.setVisible(true, true);
    frameAnimation.start();
}
frameAnimation.stop();
```